# How to pass in Strings and combined them to make a new variable(String concatenation trouble)?

Tags: java, regex, string-concatenation

I am working on a project and I dont know how to properly parse some input for example a1 = ("hello" + "World"). a1 is a cell that I made and i am trying to at the end put helloworld into that cell. This is one of my classes that I use parse input. When I use numbers it works fine but not with Strings. Im just trying to be able to parse an input like ("hi" + "man") to himan. I just want to be able to parse out the spaces and the plus sign and make himan into a single string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ParseInput {
    private static String inputs;
    static int col;
    private static int row;
    private static String operation;
    private static Value field;


    public static void parseInput(String input){
         //splits the input at each regular expression match. \w is used for letters and \d && \D for integers
        inputs = input;
        Scanner tokens = new Scanner(inputs);
        String[] strings = input.split("=");
        String s1 = strings[0].trim(); // a1
        String s2 = strings[1].trim(); // "Hello" + "World"

        strings = s2.split("\\+");
        String s3 = strings[0].trim().replaceAll("^\"", "").replaceAll("\"$", ""); // Hello
        String s4 = strings[1].trim().replaceAll("^\"", "").replaceAll("\"$", ""); // World
        String field = s3 + s4;

        String colString = s1.replaceAll("[\\d]", ""); // a
        String rowString = s1.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""); // 1
        int col = colString.charAt(0) - 'a'; // 0
        int row = Integer.parseInt(rowString);
        TextValue fieldvalue = new TextValue(field); 

        Spreadsheet.changeCell(row, col, fieldvalue);

        String none0 = tokens.next();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String none1 = tokens.next();
        operation = tokens.nextLine().substring(1);
        String[] holder =  new String[2];
        String regex = "(?<=[\\w&&\\D])(?=\\d)";   
        holder = none0.split(regex);
        row = Integer.parseInt(holder[1]);
        col = 0;
        int counter = -1;
        char temp = holder[0].charAt(0);
        char check = 'a';
        while(check <= temp){
            if(check == temp){
                col = counter +1;
            }
            counter++;
            check = (char) (check + 1);
        }
         System.out.println(col);
         System.out.println(row);
         System.out.println(operation);
         setField(Value.parseValue(operation));

         Spreadsheet.changeCell(row, col, fieldvalue);

    }

    public static Value getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public static void setField(Value field) {
        ParseInput.field = field;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Just did. I just want to know how to  parse input properly like for example a1 = ("hel" + "lo") will change to hello.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove spaces, it's a one-liner...

```
input = input.replaceAll("[\\s+\"]", "");
```

The other way to do this would be to simply remove all "non word" chars (defined as 0-9, a-z, A-Z and the underscore):

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Comment: Thanks but Im trying to parse out the spaces and the plus sign. I Want to be able to for example  type in a1 = ("hel" + "lo") and then it will change to hello.

Comment: Edited the answer to remove whitespace, plus sign and doublequotes. You can add other chars in there as you like. Also, see alternative answer

Answer (score -1):

Use a `StringBuilder`. `String` is immutable in Java, which means you will be creating a new instance every time you want to combine two strings. Use the `append()` method (it accepts just about anything) to add something onto the end.

```
StringBuilder input = "";
input.append("hel").append("lo");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is the documentation for it. Take a look.